# Grouping similar month and year in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dictionary containing dates and amounts

```
records = [
           {'date':'01 Feb 2020', 'amount':1000}, {'date':'03 Mar 2020', 'amount':2000}, 
           {'date':'22 Mar 2020', 'amount':3000},
           {'date':'12 Jan 2019', 'amount':1000}, {'date': '02 Feb 2018', 'amount':2500}, 
           {'date': '02 Mar 2020', 'amount':2500}, {'date': '11 Feb 2020', 'amount':1200}

        ]
```

I am trying to achieve something . I want to group similar month and year and get something like this:

```
result = [{'Feb 2020':[1000, 1200]}, {'March 2020':[2000, 3000, 2500]}, {'Jan 2019':[1000]}]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 5.5. Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [Tutorial - 5. Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can convert all the individual `date` fields into only months:

```
records_months = [{"date": item['date'][3:], "amount": item["amount"]} for item in records]
```

Then, we can collapse all the individual elements into the same dates. We will use `defaultdict` to initialize a dictionary with list values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_records = defaultdict(list)
for item in records_months:
    date = item['date']
    new_records[date].append(item['amount'])

print(dict(new_records))

# Output: {'Feb 2018': [2500],
#          'Feb 2020': [1000, 1200],
#          'Jan 2019': [1000],
#          'Mar 2020': [2000, 3000, 2500]}
```

Comment: This doesn't get the desired output: `[{'Feb 2020':[1000, 1200]}, {'March 2020':[2000, 3000, 2500]}, {'Jan 2019':[1000]}]`. Although keeping it as a dict makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to do the grouping, split `"date"` on the first whitespace with `maxsplit=1` to separate the day from the month and year, then use the month and year string as the grouping key.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

records = [
    {"date": "01 Feb 2020", "amount": 1000},
    {"date": "03 Mar 2020", "amount": 2000},
    {"date": "22 Mar 2020", "amount": 3000},
    {"date": "12 Jan 2019", "amount": 1000},
    {"date": "02 Feb 2018", "amount": 2500},
    {"date": "02 Mar 2020", "amount": 2500},
    {"date": "11 Feb 2020", "amount": 1200},
]

d = defaultdict(list)
for record in records:
    day, month_year = record["date"].split(maxsplit=1)
    d[month_year].append(record["amount"])

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Feb 2020': [1000, 1200], 'Mar 2020': [2000, 3000, 2500], 'Jan 2019': [1000], 'Feb 2018': [2500]})
```

<sup>`defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, so you can treat the result as a normal dictionary.</sup>

If you don't want to use libraries, then [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) can be used here as well:

```py
d = {}
for record in records:
    day, month_year = record["date"].split(maxsplit=1)
    d.setdefault(month_year, []).append(record["amount"])

print(d)
```

Or even a solution where you initialise the empty lists yourself for missing keys:

```py
d = {}
for record in records:
    day, month_year = record["date"].split(maxsplit=1)
    if month_year not in d:
        d[month_year] = []
    d[month_year].append(record["amount"])

print(d)
```

Which will give a similar result:

```
{'Feb 2020': [1000, 1200], 'Mar 2020': [2000, 3000, 2500], 'Jan 2019': [1000], 'Feb 2018': [2500]}
```

The benefit of the first two solutions is that empty lists are initialised for you when keys are missing.

Finally, if we want to have a list of dictionaries as the result, you can construct a list comprehension:

```py
[{k: v} for k, v in d.items()]
```

Which will give you:

```
[{'Feb 2020': [1000, 1200]}, {'Mar 2020': [2000, 3000, 2500]}, {'Jan 2019': [1000]}, {'Feb 2018': [2500]}]
```

Although keeping the result as a dictionary makes more sense, since it's easier to access keys later on and the keys are already unique.